# Where can I assume null characters will be added automatically in C?

Tags: c, string, null

I know these two instances will automatically add the null terminator:

```
char test[100] = "Null terminator will follow me";
```

and

```
/*...String already initialised*/
sprintf(test,"Null terminator will follow me");
```

But where else will this happen in regular C usage?

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant; calling it a "null terminator" would be less confusing.

Comment: So, calling it 0-terminator (zero-terminator) would be an alternative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, `NULL` is a macro that expands to a null *pointer* constant; using that term to refer to a null *character* will cause confusion at best, incorrect code at worst.

C strings are terminated by a null character, `'\0'`, sometimes referred to as "NUL". That's part of the C Standard's definition of the word "string":

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
>   character.

*Almost* any string literal (delimited by `"` characters) implicitly includes a null terminator -- even if there's also an explicit one. For example:

```
 "abc\0def"
```

refers to an array with the contents:

```
 { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0' }
```

The one exception to this is when the string literal is used as an initializer for an array of exactly the same length as the literal:

```
 char nonterminated[5] = "12345";
```

(C++ doesn't have this special case, and makes the above declaration illegal.)

Most of the `str*()` functions declared in `<string.h>` will give you properly null-terminated strings *if* you use them properly.  (The `strncpy()` function is a [notable exception](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html); I suggest avoiding it.)

Any function whose documentation says it deals with "strings" will either require or produce a properly null-terminated string (assuming that both the function and its documentation are correct).

Comment: Do you mind explaining how NULL is not \0? On the ASCII table decimal zero is NULL, which is the same value as \0.

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: As it happens, the ASCII standard does refer to character 0 as "NULL". Most ASCII charts I've seen refer to it as "NUL". The difference is that the macro `NULL` in C, defined in `<stddef.h>` and several other headers, is a null *pointer* constant. Due to some quirks in the C language, `NULL` may be defined as `0`, and `'\0'` is also a valid null pointer constant. But it's important to distinguish between characters and pointers, which are entirely different things. You can write `void *ptr = '\0';`, but that doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: Furthermore, `NULL` may be defined as `((void*)0)`, which is a null pointer constant but may not be assigned to a `char` object.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term object. Isn't that an Object oriented language term? Also, by "pointer constant" you're saying those headers allocate 8-bits of memory, assign it the value zero, and then give it the "identifier" NULL? Apologies if my vocabulary is inaccurate.

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: The word "object" is used in various ways. The C standard defines it as a "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values" (basically a variable). The headers don't allocate any storage for `NULL`; it's a macro, which means that any reference to `NULL` in your program is expanded at compile time to the appropriate token sequence, just as if you had written `0` or `((void*)0)` rather than `NULL`. Whether that results in anything being allocated depends on what you do with it.

Answer (score 3):

The double quotes implies a terminating null character. If you write

```
char mystr[5] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
```

there will be no termination. However, notice that if you write

```
char mystr[5] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
```

the string will be null terminated as well, since elements left out of a initializer will implicitly be set to 0.

Comment: Is a null terminator added if size not specified,  char mystr[] = {'A', 'B', 'C'}; , ?

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you use the "This is a string" notation in C, it means a pointer to a character array, where the last character is '\0'.

Answer (score 2):

Many library defined functions provide the functionality of automatically adding null terminator, given are examples of those functions

```
main()
{
char string[100];
scanf("%s",string);  //here,the function scanf automatically terminates the entered string with a null character('\0').
}
```

or

```
main()
{
 char string[100];
 gets(string); //gets function also terminates automatically the function with a null character('\0').
```

But if use functions like **getchar()**, **getche()** iteratively to read a string ,they don't automatically put terminating null character at the end of string.
We have to explicitly put it.The given piece of code illustrates the situation

```
//iterative use of getchar function to read string
main()
{
  char string[100],ch;
  int loc=0;
  printf("enter a line of text");
  while((ch=getchar())!='\n'))
        string[loc++]=ch; 

  line[loc]='\0';  //null character is added explicitly
  printf("the text entered is %s",string);

}
```

Also, all **string literals** are automatically terminated by a null character so we don't need to put it explicitly.

For example -"hello"

We see 5 characters in the given string, but it actually contains 6 characters. The last character is '\0'.

Answer (score 1):

1) Every string literal gets the null terminator implicitly.

2) Many C library functions will automatically null terminate the result. For example the sprintf function will print all the arguments and then append a null terminator. String copy functions in the c library normally do the same thing.