# Curious array overwrite

Tags: c, overwrite

I wrote the following c program:

```
int main() 
 {
     char a[1];
     char b[6]="hello\0";
     int c,  i;

     for(i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++) 
         a[i] = c;
     for(i = 0; i  < 5; i++) 
         printf("%c", b[i]);

 }
```

Why when I give "bye" in input the program print "helby"? 
I thought 'b' should be saved in a[0], 'y' in b[0] and 'e' in b[1].
Thank you in advice!

Comment: That `while` loop has the syntax of a `for` loop and does not compile. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: your result is not reproduced :( ... check this : https://ideone.com/oAWAiw , here we get `hello` as output when input is `bye`

Comment: It is correct that `'b'` is stored in `a[0]`, everything else is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think this depends entirely on the compiler. When I ran this on ideone.com, it printed `hello`. Note also that `"hello\0" is a string literal that includes an implicit null as well as the explicit null you encoded, so it actually has length 7. (See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943411/do-string-literals-that-end-with-a-null-terminator-contain-an-extra-null-termina), for instance.)

Comment: your result is not reproduced :( ... check this : https://ideone.com/oAWAiw , here we get `hello` as output when input is `bye`

Comment: The very first statement in `main` is `char a[1];` so within the corrected loop `a[i] = c;` will break the system with *undefined behaviour*. Do not try playing tricks in C, there are few enough safeguards anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume that `a` is immediately followed by `b` in memory.  That is not necessarily the case.

Reading/writing past the end of an array is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so compilers are free to arrange local variables in any order they choose.

On my particular machine, if `b` is declared before `a`, then `a` appears just before `b` in memory and I get the output you expect.  However, as you can see from the other answers and comments that behavior is not reliable because of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Why when I give "bye" in input the program print "helby"?

In the program you are trying to access beyond the bounds of array `a[]` in this loop:

```
 for(i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++) 
     a[i] = c; //only defined behaviour for `i = 0`
```

for example when you give `bye` as input,

```
a[0] -> overwritten with b
a[1] -> undefined behaviour as you are accessing out of bounds
a[2] -> same as a[1]
```

here you can see that nowhere the `b[]` array is changed.

it leads to **undefined behaviour**. So your output can be anything *(from nothing to everything)*