# Why don't char arrays with separate chars end with a null-terminator unlike string literals?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, sizeof, null-terminated

I was playing around with char arrays in c++ and wrote this program:

```
int main()
{

char text[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };  //arrays initialised like this 
                                            //will have a size of the number 
                                            //of elements that you see

char text2[] = "hello"; //arrays initialised like this will have a size of 
                        //the number of elements that you see + 1 (0 on the 
                        //end to show where the end is

cout << endl;

cout << "The size of the first array is: " << sizeof(text) << endl;

cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(text); i++)
{
    cout << i << ":" << text[i] << endl;
}
cout << endl;

cout << "The size of the first array is: " << sizeof(text2) << endl;

cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(text2); i++)
{
    cout << i << ":" << text2[i] << endl;
}
cout << endl;

cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

This program gives me the output:

```
The size of the first array is: 5

0:h
1:e
2:l
3:l
4:o

The size of the first array is: 6

0:h
1:e
2:l
3:l
4:o
5:
```

My question is: Is there a particular reason that initializing a char array with separate chars will not have a null terminator (0) on the end unlike initializing a char array with a string literal?

Comment: it would be rather annoying if each `char` array had a null implicitly added, while for string literals thats just what you want

Comment: It is just the way the language works.  When you take control and specify what you want (`{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }`), that is what you get.

Comment: Nice observation! I guess the answer is, "What if I actually want an array of `char`s that isn't a string? How could I get that otherwise?"

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17943529/1132334

Comment: Because sometimes you want an array of bytes instead of "characters"? It really depends on the use-case, so the compiler cant make any assumptions.

Comment: maybe what causes your confusing is that not each `char` array is used to store character sequences. `char` is basically just a type like `int` or `float` that can hold some values. Being used as a string is just one usecase, though a very common one

Comment: Odd duplicate that Community spotted, no? That did not mention the explicit char array.

Comment: @Bathsheba The answer did, albeit maybe not as directly as you like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821770/2757035

Comment: @underscore_d: Odd policy that. I could create a question "what is the C++ standard", answer it with a verbatim copy of the C++ standard, and close *every* C++ question to that answer. For me a duplicate has to be "the question is an exact duplicate of this question". Disk is cheap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A curly braces initializer just provides the specified values for an array (or if the array is larger, the rest of the items are defaulted). It's not a string even if the items are `char` values. `char` is just the smallest integer type.

A string literal denotes a zero-terminated sequence of values.

That's all.

Comment: s/signed integer type/integer type since we don't know what the signedness of `char` is.

Comment: Just in case Cheers and hth. - Alf is now in the pub, I've made a cheeky edit.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thanks everyone for the comments/answers.

Answer (score 1):

Informally, it's the second quotation character in a string literal of the form `"foo"` that adds the NUL-terminator.

In C++, `"foo"` is a `const char[4]` type, which *decays* to a `const char*` in certain situations.

It's just how the language works, that's all. And it's very useful since it dovetales nicely with all the standard library functions that model a string as a pointer to the first element in a NUL-terminated array of `char`s.

Splicing in an extra element with something like `char text[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };` would be *really* annoying and it could introduce inconsistency into the language. Would you do the same thing for `signed char`, and `unsigned char`, for example? And what about `int8_t`?

Answer (score 1):

You can terminate it yourself in multiple ways:

```
char text1[6] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
char text2[sizeof "hello"] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
char text3[] = "hello"; // <--- my personal favourite
```

Answer (score 1):

A string literal like for example this `"hello"` has a type of a constant character array and initializwd the following way

```
const char string_literal_hello[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

As it is seen the type of the string literal is `const char[6]`. It contains six characters.

Thus this declaration

```
char text2[] = "hello";
```

that can be also written like

```
char text2[] = { "hello" };
```

in fact is substituted for the following declaration

```
char text2[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

That is then a string literal is used as an initializer of a character array all its characters are used to initialize the array.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a particular reason that initializing a char array with separate chars will not have a null terminator (0)

The reason is because that syntax...

```
Type name[] = { comma separated list };
```

...is used for initializing arrays **of any type**.  Not just `char`.

The `"quoted string"` syntax is shorthand for a very specific type of array that assumes a null terminator is desired.

Answer (score 0):

When you designate a double quote delimited set of adjacent characters (a string literal), it is assumed that what you want is a string. And a string in C means an array of characters that is null-terminated, because that's what the functions that operate on strings (`printf`, `strcpy`, etc...) expect. So the compiler automatically adds that null terminator for you.

When you provide a brace delimited, comma separated list of single quote delimited characters, it is assumed that you don't want a string, but you want an array of the exact characters you specified. So no null terminator is added.

C++ inherits this behavior.

Comment: Note though that in C, `"foo"` is a `char[4]` type although it's UB to try to modify it. Also note that `'h'` is an `int` type in C. In other words, the languages diverge so much in this area, I avoided making the comparison.